# MySQL query outputting more results in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am using a sql query using the Joomla Framework, and it is almost looping around results.

Here is the syntax, which is outputting almost triple the results than expected.

```
->select(array('a.virtuemart_custom_id', 'a.virtuemart_product_id', 'b.virtuemart_custom_id', 'b.value'))
->from('#__virtuemart_product_customfields AS a')
->join('INNER', '#__virtuemart_product_custom_plg_param AS b ON (a.virtuemart_custom_id = b.virtuemart_custom_id)')
->where('a.virtuemart_product_id='.$this->product->virtuemart_product_id)
->order('b.virtuemart_custom_id ASC');
```

From phpMyAdmin, it should only retain 7 results.

[image]

Is my SQL wrong here? why is it outputting and looping?

my results output:

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2300cc| ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDROU.png) => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2200cc| ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2300cc| ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2300cc| ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2300cc| ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2100cc| ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2200cc| ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2200cc| ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2200cc| ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2300cc| ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2200cc| ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2200cc| ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2200cc| ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2200cc| ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2200cc| ) [15] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2300cc| ) [16] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2200cc| ) [17] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2300cc| ) [18] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2300cc| ) [19] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2200cc| ) [20] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |4 Berth| ) [21] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2| ) [22] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2 Berth| ) [23] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |5| ) [24] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |4| ) [25] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |6| ) [26] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |6| ) [27] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |5| ) [28] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2 Berth| ) [29] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |4| ) [30] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2| ) [31] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |4| ) [32] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2 Berth| ) [33] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2| ) [34] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |4| ) [35] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |6 Berth| ) [36] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2| ) [37] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |2| ) [38] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |4| ) [39] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |3| ) [40] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Coachbuilt| ) [41] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Low Profile| ) [42] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Coachbuilt| ) [43] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Coachbuilt| ) [44] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Coachbuilt| ) [45] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Low Profile| ) [46] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Low Profile| ) [47] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Coachbuilt| ) [48] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Panel Van| ) [49] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Low Profile| ) [50] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Low Profile| ) [51] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Panel Van| ) [52] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Coachbuilt| ) [53] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Coachbuilt| ) [54] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Panel Van| ) [55] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Low Profile| ) [56] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Panel Van| ) [57] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Low Profile| ) [58] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Coachbuilt| ) [59] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Coachbuilt| ) [60] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [61] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [62] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [63] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [64] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [65] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [66] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [67] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [68] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [69] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |34133| ) [70] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [71] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [72] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [73] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [74] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |20994| ) [75] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [76] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [77] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [78] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [79] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |0| ) [80] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |NEW (2013)| ) [81] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |NEW (2012)| ) [82] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |NEW (2013)| ) [83] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |NEW (2013)| ) [84] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |NEW (2012)| ) [85] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |NEW (2013)| ) [86] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |NEW (2012)| ) [87] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |X111 2233| ) [88] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |NEW (2013)| ) [89] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |NEW (2013)| ) [90] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |NEW (2012)| ) [91] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |YX59 AZL| ) [92] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |NEW (2013)| ) [93] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |NEW (2013)| ) [94] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [95] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [96] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [97] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [98] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [99] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [100] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [101] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [102] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [103] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [104] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [105] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [106] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [107] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [108] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [109] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [110] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [111] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [112] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [113] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |Manual| ) [114] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L19'8| ) [115] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |20'7"| ) [116] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L23'3"| ) [117] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L20'8| ) [118] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L21'7"| ) [119] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L25'7| ) [120] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L24'7| ) [121] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L22'8| ) [122] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |20'3| ) [123] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |18'6| ) [124] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L23'4| ) [125] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |20'8| ) [126] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L17'9| ) [127] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L23'7| ) [128] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L19'8| ) [129] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |23'7"| ) [130] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L24'7"| ) [131] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L17'9| ) [132] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L20'11| ) [133] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44 [virtuemart_product_id] => 20 [value] => |L19'8| ) )

Comment: If there are some duplicate values you observed, try using group by then...

Comment: Use GROUP BY virtuemart_product_id

Comment: any idea how to use group by with joomla syntax?

Comment: group only returns 1 result..

Comment: @SMacFadyen:print your query and check whether it is same as what you are running in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Pls. add the query you are using on phpmyadmin, so we may compare both.